# How to resolve the Error : nlp.add_pipe` now takes the string name of the registered component factory, not a callable component

Tags: python, parsing, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am using empty blank spacy model to train my own data for ner. I am training my model to for entities from the train_data.

```
nlp = spacy.blank('en')

def train_model(train_data) :
    if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
        nlp.add_pipe(ner)        
    
    for _ ,annotation in train_data :
        for ent in annotation['entities']:
            ner.add_label(ent[2])
           
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
        for itn in range(15):
            print("Starting Iteration"   + str(itn))
            random.shuffle(train_data)
            losses = {}
            index = 0
        
            for text, annotations in train_data :
                try:
                    nlp.update([text], [annotations], sgd=optimizer, drop=0.20,
                       losses=losses)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
            print('Losses', losses)
```

I am getting the following error.
`nlp.add_pipe` now takes the string name of the registered component factory, not a callable component. Expected string, but got <spacy.pipeline.ner.EntityRecognizer object at 0x0000022969A29C88> (name: 'None').

- If you created your component with `nlp.create_pipe('name')`: remove nlp.create_pipe and call `nlp.add_pipe('name')` instead.
- If you passed in a component like `TextCategorizer()`: call `nlp.add_pipe` with the string name instead, e.g. `nlp.add_pipe('textcat')`.
- If you're using a custom component: Add the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory` (for class components / factories) to your custom component and assign it a name, e.g. `@Language.component('your_name')`. You can then run `nlp.add_pipe('your_name')` to add it to the pipeline.

Comment: It looks like you are using old spaCy v2 sample code with spaCy v3. I recommend you read through the spaCy docs on training a model. https://spacy.io/usage/training

Answer (score 4):

Concerning the error - replace

```
ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
nlp.add_pipe(ner)
```

with

```
ner = nlp.add_pipe('ner')
```

Comment: i already replaced with the code above , but then it is not training the model , it is just printing the Starting Iteration 1 Starting Iteration 2 ......  like this till Starting Iteration 14 . But not actually training the model neither giving losses value.

Comment: Have you checked whether nlp.update() is throwing an error, which fails silently due to except clause and pass in it?